# Kinesis Firehose putting JSON objects in S3 without seperator comma

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

Before sending the data I am using JSON.stringify to the data and it looks like this

```
{"data": [{"key1": value1, "key2": value2}, {"key1": value1, "key2": value2}]}
```

But once it passes through AWS API Gateway and Kinesis Firehose puts it to S3 it looks like this

```
    {
     "key1": value1, 
     "key2": value2
    }{
     "key1": value1, 
     "key2": value2
    }
```

The seperator comma between the JSON objects are gone but I need it to process data properly.

Template in the API Gateway:

```
#set($root = $input.path('$'))
{
    "DeliveryStreamName": "some-delivery-stream",
    "Records": [
#foreach($r in $root.data)
#set($data = "{
    ""key1"": ""$r.value1"",
    ""key2"": ""$r.value2""
}")
    {
        "Data": "$util.base64Encode($data)"
    }#if($foreach.hasNext),#end
#end
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had this same problem recently, and the only answers I was able to find were basically just to add line breaks ("\n") to the end of every JSON message whenever you posted them to the Kinesis stream, or to use a raw JSON decoder method of some sort that can process concatenated JSON objects without delimiters.

I posted a python code solution which can be found over here on a related Stack Overflow post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49417680/1546785

Answer (score 2):

One approach you could consider is to configure data processing for your Kinesis Firehose delivery stream by adding a Lambda function as its data processor, which would be executed before finally delivering the data to the S3 bucket.

```yaml
DeliveryStream:
  ...
  Type: AWS::KinesisFirehose::DeliveryStream
  Properties:
    DeliveryStreamType: DirectPut
    ExtendedS3DestinationConfiguration:
      ...
      BucketARN: !GetAtt MyDeliveryBucket.Arn
      ProcessingConfiguration:
        Enabled: true
        Processors:
          - Parameters:
              - ParameterName: LambdaArn
                ParameterValue: !GetAtt MyTransformDataLambdaFunction.Arn
            Type: Lambda
    ...
```

And in the Lambda function, ensure that `'\n'` is appended to the record's JSON string, see below the Lambda function `myTransformData.ts` in Node.js:

```
import {
  FirehoseTransformationEvent,
  FirehoseTransformationEventRecord,
  FirehoseTransformationHandler,
  FirehoseTransformationResult,
  FirehoseTransformationResultRecord,
} from 'aws-lambda';

const createDroppedRecord = (
  recordId: string
): FirehoseTransformationResultRecord => {
  return {
    recordId,
    result: 'Dropped',
    data: Buffer.from('').toString('base64'),
  };
};

const processData = (
  payloadStr: string,
  record: FirehoseTransformationEventRecord
) => {
  let jsonRecord;
  // ...
  // Process the orginal payload,
  // And create the record in JSON
  return jsonRecord;
};

const transformRecord = (
  record: FirehoseTransformationEventRecord
): FirehoseTransformationResultRecord => {
  try {
    const payloadStr = Buffer.from(record.data, 'base64').toString();
    const jsonRecord = processData(payloadStr, record);
    if (!jsonRecord) {
      console.error('Error creating json record');
      return createDroppedRecord(record.recordId);
    }
    return {
      recordId: record.recordId,
      result: 'Ok',
      // Ensure that '\n' is appended to the record's JSON string.
      data: Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(jsonRecord) + '\n').toString('base64'),
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error processing record ${record.recordId}: ', error);
    return createDroppedRecord(record.recordId);
  }
};

const transformRecords = (
  event: FirehoseTransformationEvent
): FirehoseTransformationResult => {
  let records: FirehoseTransformationResultRecord[] = [];
  for (const record of event.records) {
    const transformed = transformRecord(record);
    records.push(transformed);
  }
  return { records };
};

export const handler: FirehoseTransformationHandler = async (
  event,
  _context
) => {
  const transformed = transformRecords(event);
  return transformed;
};
```

Once the newline delimiter is in place, AWS services such as Athena will be able to work properly with the JSON record data in the S3 bucket, not [just seeing the first JSON record only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46605869/athena-can-only-see-the-first-json-record-written-to-firehose-by-kinesis-analyti).

Answer (score 0):

Once AWS Firehose dumps the JSON objects to s3, it's perfectly possible to read the individual JSON objects from the files.

Using **Python** you can use the `raw_decode` function from the `json` package

```
from json import JSONDecoder, JSONDecodeError
import re
import json
import boto3

NOT_WHITESPACE = re.compile(r'[^\s]')

def decode_stacked(document, pos=0, decoder=JSONDecoder()):
    while True:
        match = NOT_WHITESPACE.search(document, pos)
        if not match:
            return
        pos = match.start()

        try:
            obj, pos = decoder.raw_decode(document, pos)
        except JSONDecodeError:
            # do something sensible if there's some error
            raise
        yield obj

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

obj = s3.Object("my-bukcet", "my-firehose-json-key.json")
file_content = obj.get()['Body'].read()
for obj in decode_stacked(file_content):
    print(json.dumps(obj))
    #  { "key1":value1,"key2":value2}
    #  { "key1":value1,"key2":value2}
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50384432/1771155

Using **Glue / Pyspark** you can use

```
import json

rdd = sc.textFile("s3a://my-bucket/my-firehose-file-containing-json-objects")
df = rdd.map(lambda x: json.loads(x)).toDF()
df.show()
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62984450/1771155

Answer (score -1):

please use this code to solve your issue

```
__Author__ = "Soumil Nitin Shah"
import json
import boto3
import base64


class MyHasher(object):
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key

    def get(self):
        keys = str(self.key).encode("UTF-8")
        keys = base64.b64encode(keys)
        keys = keys.decode("UTF-8")
        return keys

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    output = []
    for record in event['records']:

        payload = base64.b64decode(record['data'])

        """Get the payload from event bridge and just get data attr """""
        serialize_payload = str(json.loads(payload)) + "\n"
        hasherHelper = MyHasher(key=serialize_payload)
        hash = hasherHelper.get()

        output_record = {
            'recordId': record['recordId'],
            'result': 'Ok',
            'data': hash
        }
        print("output_record", output_record)

        output.append(output_record)

    return {'records': output}
```